# css fixed element always visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

My problem: 
I generated an .art-obj1631017189 (which is a logo) and I want to set its position to fixed. It works, but when I'm scrolling and it reaches the content section, my object goes behind content (which is item-layout).

I would like to always see my element in the foreground when I scroll down.

Any ideas?

```
.art-object1631017189
{     
    display: block;    
    left: 22.16%;    
    margin-left: -40px;    
    position: fixed;    
    top: 0px;    
    width: 184px;    
    height: 209px;    
    background-image: url('images/object1631017189.png');    
    background-position: 0 0;    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    z-index: 4;    
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: increase z-index

Comment: please post some html and check your z-indexes.

Comment: Are there objects with a higher z-index in the content section?

Comment: @madalinivascu: That's an *answer*, not a *comment*. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder to short for a answer

Comment: If increasing `z-index` does not work, give the container, which contains both, the content section and your image `position: relative`.

Comment: @madalinivascu: Sometimes answers are short. That's fine, provided they really are answers.

Comment: .art-sheet{z-index: auto !important}

Comment: @Palyika: What is that meant to tell us?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the answer, but hard to tell with so little to work with:

```
.art-object1631017189
{     
    display: block;    
    left: 22.16%;    
    margin-left: -40px;    
    position: fixed;    
    top: 0px;    
    width: 184px;    
    height: 209px;    
    background-image: url('images/object1631017189.png');    
    background-position: 0 0;    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    z-index: 1000; // Increased z-index
}
```

Comment: I've already tried to increase z-index, but not success. Increased to highest than the css contains

Comment: I found the answer! I had to move upper the div class="art-object" line, directly under header class!

Comment: Same behaviour. Can't figure why it works like this

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
In the index.html I had to move few line up the `<div class="art-obj1631017189">` line, directly under `<header>` class.

Comment: In future you should post the relevant CSS _&_ HTML, then people would be able to identify the problem you were having instead of trying to guess solutions. There still may be a problem with your code, however, as the position of the `<div>` shouldn't matter if the `<header>` element is statically/relatively positioned with a lower `z-index`.